# Which types of errors should stop the system, in released php web system?

Tags: php

While developing a php web system, setting `E_ALL | E_STRICT` to error_reporting and taking care of all kind of errors including notice errors is good practice.

But in the released system, should I stop the system when notice error occurred?

Or should I stop the system only when E_ERROR occurred and ignore all other errors such as E_WARNING, E_NOTICE, or E_STRICT?

Which types of errors should I handle in my custom error handler and stop(exit) the system?

Comment: Warnings should definitely stop the system (but don't leave the original error/exception handlers, write your own that don't disclose any error information). Lesser error levels are less definitive, but you should at least log them and mail the reports to yourself - that will motivate you to fix them :)

Comment: @DCoder thanks for good advices! 
Could you tell me why you should stop the system when E_WARNING occurred?

Comment: In most cases where correctness is more important than high availability, "failing fast" is preferable to "moving on no matter what". A warning usually means something went really wrong and moving on will only make things worse. Consider the most common question on this site - ["mysql_fetch_ expects parameter..., boolean given"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+fetch+boolean+given). If you don't halt your script on the first warning, you're going to get a long list of repeating warnings and possibly even mess up other data by using the results of the failed query in further processing.

Comment: @DCoder thanks for your comment. I will stop my system when warnings occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you develop a code you should take care of any warning including notices.

For production your should not really halt on errors. Instead you can use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to manage any errors such as `E_USER_ERROR`, `E_USER_WARNING`, `E_USER_NOTICE`. Redirect client to custom page, display a custom message for any type of error. The point is not to leave the default error information.

You should always have a system that reports any errors encountered to yourself (via e-mail or such) on production servers and take care of them as soon as possible.

On [php.net/set_error_handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) you have plenty of examples that will make your life a lot easier and help you track errors and warnings.

Comment: thanks for useful information!
In all of examples of error handlers in [php.net/set_error_handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) don't call `exit` when E_WARNING (not E_USER_WARNING) occured.
Do you think you don't need to show error screen or message to users and stop(exit) the system when E_WARNING occurred?

Comment: That is your decision, Warning don't need `exit`, they are just warnings (undefined indexes, deprecated functions, etc ..)